# How to enable <button> tag using C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I see the html like this:

`<button class="submit-button" disabled="disabled" tabindex="0">submit</button>`

how to enable the button using C#?

Comment: C# is server side language, you use javascript for client side scripting

Comment: Hi Caknun, welcome to SO. You need to provide a lot more info on your problem for us to help you. Have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for some info on asking questions, and search the web some on the difference between server side (e.g. C#) code and client side code (e.g. JavaScript). You can edit your question any time (which you should, otherwise it may be closed by mods).

Answer (score 1):

You do it with `javascript` not `C#`, C# is for server side programming.

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("theId").disabled = false;
```

**`jQuery` version:**

```
$('#theId').prop('disabled', false);
```

---

**Update:**

I've just notice you use a button for submit, there is `<input type="submit" />` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* put an ASP literal in place of the `disabled` value.

```
<button class="submit-button" disabled="<asp:Literal id='disabledValue' runat='server'></asp:Literal>" tabindex="0">submit</button>
```

Then, in the C#, set the `Text` of that literal to whichever value you please:

```
disabledValue.Text = 'disabled' // or 'enabled' or whatever you please
```

Answer (score 0):

since I have no idea what your final goal is, I might just answer your question.

Give the button an ID and a runat="server" Attribute like this

```
<button class="submit-button" disabled="disabled" tabindex="0" id="mybutton" runat="server">submit</button>
```

In Code-Behind (C#) you can  now access the button and do something like this

```
mybutton.Disabled = false;
```

Javascript has already been mentioned, so just decide what you need.